# How to make geany or vi understand Maxima (or any other less known) syntax

Tags: programming, geany, vi, syntax-highlighting

I tend to program a lot in a symbolic language called [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), but I haven't found any editor that highlights its syntax. Is there I way I can make `vi` or `geany` (or whatever)  understand this syntax and highlight the code accordingly?

More generally, is there a way to do it for any other lesser known language?

Comment: For Geany check the documentation at http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#filetype-definition-files and if this is not working out how to extend it http://geany.org/manual/hacking.html#adding-a-filetype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a syntax highlighting file for gedit at this link:
https://www.ma.utexas.edu/pipermail/maxima/2013/031644.html
https://www.dropbox.com/s/thoibnymcigd457/maxima.lang

(Place maxima.lang into /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/ for 
gedit3 or /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/ for gedit2).

I have not tried this myself, but I saw it is indeed a text highlighting file for gedit and it should work.

edit: just for completeness, here http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=398 is one for vi, even though it seems quite old.

Comment: Great, it works. On a side note: is there a way I can use that file for geany or vi. Gedit is like my least favorite editor...

Answer (score 0):

KATE (KDE Advanced Text Editor) has native support for Maxima syntax highlighting.  KATE will automatically apply Maxima syntax highlighting to MAC files, but this can also be set manually using "Tools" --> "Highlighting" --> "Scientific" --> "Maxima".

https://www.kate-editor.org/

Comment: You can also highlight Maxima syntax for MediaWiki and HTML using HighlightJS: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Highlightjs_Integration